# How to handle the Back Button Grails Webflow

Tags: grails, back-button, spring-webflow

We have a Grails 1.3.7 Application and are using Webflow for a 2 step process. They can end the Process using a Link.

Often, after they are finished, they notice that there are still some changes to be made, and instead of using the edit Button they are using their browsers "back" button. This creates a new Flow, and the Users are confused that their changes are lost (the changes are saved, but they just started editing a new Item). Another interesting fact is that they then are already on page 2 of the Flow, so it does not look like the flow is completely stopped.

Currently i am trying to prevent back button presses at the next page, but if a User clicks continue on the Popup, they will still go back. What solution would you suggest? Is there a solution to prevent jumping in an already ended flow? Can I display an Error Message?

Could Grails Webflow maybe the false tool for the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. We do not use Grails Webflow for this process anymore, because it is to limiting. Lesson learned: only use webflow if you really want to lock the user into a flow.